# Add WMS in QGIS gives an error with Map request failed [error:Host http not found url:http://http//

Tags: qgis, wms

I got an URL from a friend who is working with Oracle MapBuilder. `http://[IP]:11188/mapviewer/wms`
I tried to get the service via ArcMap and it was working.

Then I tried my beloved QGIS and there is a problem. I get the connection running and all layers are shown in the "Add Layer(s) from a WM(T)S Server". I choose a layer and it gets integrated in the Layers window. But somehow there is no map. It is the same problem for all layers.

When I check the log Messages I can see the problem

```
Map request failed [error:Host http not found
url:http://http//[IP]/:11188/mapviewer/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=35.02831983698249729,31.49752950471350132,35.04319025529049725,31.50711888517620096&SRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=982&HEIGHT=633&LAYERS=GT_BLOCKS_MB&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=120&MAP_RESOLUTION=120&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:120&TRANSPARENT=TRUE]
```

The beginning of the URL is the problem

```
http://http//
```

and the part with the port

```
/:11188
```

.

How can I fix the problem???

Comment: What happens if you leave the http off?

Comment: When I just use [IP]:11188/mapviewer/wms the URL gets replaced by / and then of course nothing works

Comment: This should be a mayor issue and should have a simple solution. Can somebody help me?